# Python: writing an item in a dict but everything is affected

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to change a single item in a dictionary, but it turns out that every items are changed.

Say there is a file `cache.py`:

```py
database = {}
```

and the `main.py` in the same directory:

```py
import cache


empty_data = {
    'chat_id': 0,
    'receive': {
        'count': 0,
        'msg_by': [],
        'cmd_by': [],
    },
}


def write_data(chat_id, user_id, msg_type):
    if chat_id in cache.database:
        data = cache.database[chat_id]
    else:
        data = empty_data
        data['chat_id'] = chat_id

    data['receive']['count'] += 1
    if 'message' in msg_type or 'msg' in msg_type:
        data['receive']['msg_by'].append(user_id)
    else:
        data['receive']['cmd_by'].append(user_id)

    cache.database[chat_id] = data

    print(cache.database)
```

Then execute this: `write_data(10001, 'Amy', 'msg')`

It prints out: `{10001: {'chat_id': 10001, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': []}}}`, which looks normal.

But after that, if another command `write_data(10002, 'Bob', 'cmd')` is executed, it turns out to be:

```
{10001: {'chat_id': 10002, 'receive': {'count': 2, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': ['Bob']}}, 10002: {'chat_id': 10002, 'receive': {'count': 2, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': ['Bob']}}}
```

However it should be:

```
{10001: {'chat_id': 10001, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': []}}, 10002: {'chat_id': 10002, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': [], 'cmd_by': ['Bob']}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one instance of your `empty_data` dict, that you update in different places.

When you do `data = empty_data`, you just make the name `data` refer to the dict that `empty_data` already referred to, you don't make a copy of it. So, in all of the places where you put this `data`, you actually put the very same dict.

You need separate, new dicts each time.

One way to do it is to make a function create a new one for you when you need it:

```
database = {}

def get_empty_data():
    empty_data = {
        'chat_id': 0,
        'receive': {
            'count': 0,
            'msg_by': [],
            'cmd_by': [],
        },
    }
    return empty_data


def write_data(chat_id, user_id, msg_type):
    if chat_id in database:
        data = database[chat_id]
    else:
        data = get_empty_data()
        data['chat_id'] = chat_id

    data['receive']['count'] += 1
    if 'message' in msg_type or 'msg' in msg_type:
        data['receive']['msg_by'].append(user_id)
    else:
        data['receive']['cmd_by'].append(user_id)

    database[chat_id] = data

    print(database)

write_data(10001, 'Amy', 'msg')
write_data(10002, 'Bob', 'msg')
```

Output:

```
{10001: {'chat_id': 10001, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': []}}}
{10001: {'chat_id': 10001, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': ['Amy'], 'cmd_by': []}},
 10002: {'chat_id': 10002, 'receive': {'count': 1, 'msg_by': ['Bob'], 'cmd_by': []}}}
```

Comment: Making a function works! Looks like `data = empty_data` in the previous code makes that every change on `data` also affects `empty_data`...